# Group and find all values that belong to n unique maximum values

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

**My dataframe:**

```
data = {'Input':[133217,133217,133217,133217,133217,133217,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426],
 'Font':[30,25,25,21,20,19,50,50,50,38,38,30,30,29]}

     Input  Font
0   133217    30
1   133217    25
2   133217    25
3   133217    21
4   133217    20
5   133217    19
6   132426    50
7   132426    50
8   132426    50
9   132426    38
10  132426    38
11  132426    30
12  132426    30
13  132426    29
```

I would like to create a new data frame containing only the values in **Font** that belong to 3 unique maximum values. For example, 3 Maximum Font values for Input 133217 are 30, 25, 21.

**Expected output:**

```
op_data = {'Input':[133217,133217,133217,133217,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426,132426],
 'Font':[30,25,25,21,50,50,50,38,38,30,30]}

     Input  Font
0   133217    30
1   133217    25
2   133217    25
3   133217    21
4   132426    50
5   132426    50
6   132426    50
7   132426    38
8   132426    38
9   132426    30
10  132426    30
```

I've tried this with groupby from pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['order'] = df.groupby('Input').cumcount()+1
```

then I considered 1,2,3 values in `df['order']`, which didn't work out as planned. Any alternative way?

Comment: You say you need 3 top values but your expected output has 4 values for the first group and 7 for the second one.

Comment: Guess, this is because 25 appears twice. So to formulate the question the otherway around: do you need duplicate values like `133217` and `25`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find unique values for each group, get the list with three max values and select rows which are in this list:

```
df.groupby('Input')['Font'].\
apply(lambda x: x[x.isin(np.sort(x.unique())[-3:])]).\
reset_index(level=0)
```

Output:

```
     Input  Font
6   132426    50
7   132426    50
8   132426    50
9   132426    38
10  132426    38
11  132426    30
12  132426    30
0   133217    30
1   133217    25
2   133217    25
3   133217    21
```

Comment: I have two other columns, if I do this I lose those columns. Is there any way to not lose values in other columns?

Comment: @DGS I've edited my answer. You can merge on the index at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I would break the task in 2 steps.

1st one is ordering the dataframe. It seems your dataframe is already ordered.

```
dft = dft.sort_values(by=['Input','Font'],ascending=False)
```

Then, groupby using 'Input' column and head(3), to get top 3 for each distinct 'Input' group:

```
dft = dft.groupby('Input').head(3)
print(dft)

    Input  Font
0  133217    30
1  133217    25
2  133217    25
6  132426    50
7  132426    50
8  132426    50
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the `pandas.DataFrame.nlargest()` function:

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Input').apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(3, 'Font'))

# 132426 6   132426    50
#        9   132426    38
#        11  132426    30
# 133217 0   133217    30
#        1   133217    25
#        3   133217    21
```

Please not, that any **duplicate** values are dropped and thus not considered.